# IV too long in PHP mcrypt_generic_init

Tags: php, tripledes

I am working on a project where all the data from the web services is being encrypted using Triple DES Encryption. In my specific case, I am receiving a query string from a URL that has been encrypted. The web service provider has given me two values for decryption: the encryption Key_192 and the initialization vector IV_192. Both these keys are 24 characters long.

When I attempt to decrypt the query string I have received in PHP, I am using the mcrypt library. When initializing the generic decrypt methods, part of my function is:

```
$key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$iv = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, '', 'cbc', '');
mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
$result = rtrim(mdecrypt_generic($cipher, $this->hex2bin($buffer)), "\0");
mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
return $result;`
```

However, when I execute that portion of my code, I receive the following message:

```
mcrypt_generic_init(): Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 24, needed: 8
```

The web services provider was not able to provide any guidance on the error, instead directing me to their VB.NET implementation which has a line like:

```
Dim cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ms, cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(KEY_192, IV_192), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
```

where they pass the two keys in directly, similar to the mcrypt_generic_init() function.

I understand that the IV size is dependent upon the cypher method (Triple DES), but am confused as to why I have an IV longer than the function appears to support. How could that be? My experience with this kind of encryption is limited, and I have been unable to decrypt the query string into anything that doesn't look like a field of random characters.

Comment: `supplied length: 24, needed: 8` means it's 16 too long.

Answer (score 1):

Run `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size()` to figure out the required IV size. For Triple DES, it will be 8. `mcrypt_generic_init()` requires a string of exactly the correct length, so you should use a shorter string (or, to do it on the fly, use `substr()`).

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP was given an IV that is too long and is trying to determine if the code is wrong or the IV.

Comment: Well, it's really both. If the string was already encrypted, allegedly using this IV, then that's incorrect, but possibly salvageable; OP should try using `substr($iv, 0, 8)` as the IV. But *code* using Triple DES and a 24-character IV is also incorrect.

Comment: I am wondering why I have a 24 character string when the cypher appears to want an 8 character string. Am I interpreting the usage of the IV incorrectly? Does it need to be manipulated or truncated before being used? That seems counterintuitive.

Comment: I don't know. Where did the 24-character string come from? Are you sure you have the right encryption algorithm? If you are, then my guess is that somebody prior to you saved the wrong IV; try just using `substr($iv, 0, 8)` as the IV and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, using the substring has produced an interesting result. I am expecting the query string to decrypt to cid=INTEGER&sessionid=INTEGER, and the cid portion is actually readable (cid=1234...). The rest of the string is still garbled though, almost like it has been partially decrypted (if that is even possible).

Comment: That is possible. Try using ebc mode instead of cbc; that is probably the issue. See also the [other modes in the PHP manual](http://us1.php.net/mcrypt_module_open). If none of those works, you may need to loop over the rest of the data, possibly looping over the rest of the provided IV as well. Hard to say without knowing more about the provider's API.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue in decrypting was caused by differences in how the mcrypt PHP library and the VB.NET libraries pad strings while encrypting. Also, with regard to the original question, only the first 8 characters of the IV are actually used. The others are discarded. Better description is located here:

http://mishu666.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/problem-and-solve-of-3des-incompatibilities-with-nets-tripledescryptoserviceprovider/